# Struggling with 2 methods writing this java class in NetBeans IDE 8.0 - probably quite basic

Tags: java, netbeans, methods

I'm trying to create a class that runs this input file:

```
package tester.test5;

/**
* @author cf0rd
*/
public class RunAddress {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Person p1 = new Person("Teri", "Politician");
Person p2 = new Person("Matt", "Teacher");
Person p3 = new Person("Ruby", "Electrician");
Person p4 = new Person("Jon", "Archivist");

Address a1 = new Address(56, "BS22 1YY");
Address a2 = new Address(101, "ZA10 9XX");
a1.setNumber(a1.getNumber() + 30);

a1.addPerson(p1);
a1.addPerson(p2);
a1.addPerson(p3);

a2.addPerson(p4);

p1.setJob("Wheel Tapper");

System.out.print("Address: " + a1);
for (Person p : a1.getPeople()) {
  System.out.printf(": %s", p);
}
System.out.println("");

System.out.print("Address: " + a2);
for (Person p : a2.getPeople()) {
  System.out.printf(": %s", p);
}
System.out.println("");

p3.setName("Maz");
System.out.printf("P3 name is %s and job is %s\n", p3.getName(), p3.getJob());

} //main

} //class
```

and outputs something like this:

**Address: 86, BS22 1YY(3): Teri(Wheel Tapper): Matt(Teacher): Ruby(Electrician)**

Key: Address: [House no], [Postcode]([Number of people]): Person 1

The class is based on this UML:

```
Address
====================
- Number : int
- Postcode : String
- People : int
====================
+ addPerson
+ getPeople
+ toString() : String
```

This is the class so far, most seems OK but what I'm struggling with are the methods addPerson (which adds a person to an address) and getPeople (which returns the list of people) - The bottom 2 methods.

```
/**
 *
 * @author cf0rd
 */
public class Address {

private int Number;
private String Postcode;
private int People;


public int getNumber() {
    return Number;
}

public void setNumber(int Number) {
    this.Number = Number;
}

public String getPostcode() {
    return Postcode;
}

public void setPostcode(String Postcode) {
    this.Postcode = Postcode;
}

public String Address;


public String Address(){
             return "Address{" + "Number=" + Number + ", Postcode=" + Postcode + ", People=" + People + '}';
}

public Array getPeople();
    Array[] Person = {p1, p2, p3, p4}
    return Person;
}  

public String addPerson(Address);
    this.Person = Person;
}


}
```

Sorry this is so long-winded, as you can probably tell I'm quite new to this and appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Edit: the second class (person) - forgot to post it!

```
  public class Person {

    private String Name;
    private String Job;


   public String getJob() {
        return Job;
    }

    public void setJob(String Job) {
        this.Job = Job;
    }


public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String Person;


    public String Person() {
        return "Person{" + "Name=" + Name + ", Job=" + Job + '}';
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

public ArrayList<Person> getPeople(){
    return people;
}  

public void addPerson(Person p){
   people.add(p);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! That's removed the errors, I'm just getting the (!) now saying "cannot find symbol: class ArrayList"

Comment: Fix your imports, in NeatBeans is Ctrl + Shift + i